# Query for number of books and avg length of lending

Tags: sql, select, join

I have a school task and can't figure out how to write the query properly. Here's the task:

We have 3 tables:

**User**:  `id`, `name`, `surname`, `address`, `credit`

**Book**:  `id`, `title`, `author`, `isbn`

**Lending**:  `user`, `book`, `borrowed_when`, `returned_when`, `return_deadline`

> Create a SQL query which will return the number of books borrowed by
>   every user and average length of lending period.

I presume it should be done with a JOIN but not sure how exactly. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post any of the code you have come up with? We can help you from there on!

Comment: I just wrote some unfinished sctratch:
SELECT * FROM Lending ... JOIN ON user=book ...

Comment: Do you understand how these tables relate to each other?  If you do, identify your primary and secondary keys.

Comment: Well, the id column is the primary key in User and Book. Lending remembers those id's in the user and book columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this to get the number of books and average lending period for each user:

```
select user, count(book), avg(datediff(day, borrowed_when,returned_when)) 
from @lending
group by user
order by user
```

This query can then be joined to your `User` table to get user details, depending on how the 2 tables are linked. I suspect it's `User.id = Lending.user`, but only you can really tell us that.